# "Votes" set for all stackexchange odata services throw exceptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Only the Votes entity set has this problem.

e.g. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Votes

500 server error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
  <innererror>
    <message>The 'VoteTypeId' property on 'Vote' could not be set to a 'Byte' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'. </message>
    <type>System.InvalidOperationException</type>
    <stacktrace>   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName)&#xD;
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )&#xD;
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()</stacktrace>
  </innererror>
</error>
```

Comment: Surprised nobody had reported this error just because it was not stopping any functionality from working (I assume). This error has been there from atleast past 2-3 weeks

Comment: So will it be fixed?

Comment: April 3rd, and still broken...

Comment: somebody needs to take ownership of the odata piece, we see very little value investing time there as our api is tons more useful

Answer (score 1):

Votes and VoteTypes, actually. As [waffles mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80051/votes-set-for-all-stackexchange-odata-services-throw-exceptions#comment311363_80051), consuming the API seems much more useful and sane than using odata, but since this was easy enough to address I [fixed it anyway](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=decb6c9ef0ac58d246a6a926d023443980f6f95d) (pending pull and deploy).